# Excluding points based on several features using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have 3 separate feature classes:

[image]

Lines: 3 pcs, do not touch eachother

Points: 6pcs, at the start and end vertex of the lines

Polygons: 1 pcs, derived from joined buffers around the points based on the top line.

I only have the geodata, no additional fields of ID's to connect the features to eachother. I want to create a new feature class with just the two points that are both within the polygon and are based on the top line.

The 2 top lines are separate even though they look linked in this resolution.

I would like the solution to be able to be reproduced in the model builder as I need to iterate this method over many scenarios.

The polygon is one feature, not 2 as I originally stated. They are a union from two previously separated buffers

Comment: Should the buffer be created in the Modelbuilder process too?

Comment: @blabbath No, that will be part of the input!

Comment: What does your model so far look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Give your lines an ID, this is a simple field calculate.
2. Extract your [end points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm), they will inherit the attributes of the lines they came from. That is what it says in the help file.
3. Select points by your top line ID and export.

In your question as you build the buffer from the top line end points, I so no need to do any spatial selection. You may want to build your buffers for other processing but a simple selection by ID will suffice for this question.

Steps 1 and 2 are a one time run of the tools, if you want to loop then have a look at a feature selection iterator in modelbuilder.